# MongoDB - Get id of the maximum value in a group by query

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection where documents look like below. I would like to get the "_id" or the entire document of those with maximum revision in each group grouped by "name".

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55aa088a58f2a8f2bd2a3793"),
    "name" : "abc",
    "revision" : 1
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55aa088a58f2a8f2bd2a3794"),
    "name" : "abc",
    "revision" : 2
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55aa088a58f2a8f2bd2a3795"),
    "name" : "def",
    "revision" : 1
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55aa088a58f2a8f2bd2a3796"),
    "name" : "def",
    "revision" : 2
}
```

In this case, I'd like to select only 2nd and 4th documents. I tried various approach including aggregation framework but couldn't do it purely in MongoDB query.

Is there a solution for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following aggregation pipeline which first sorts the documents by the revision field descending and then **[`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** by the name field, add another field that gets the full document by using the **[`$first`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first)** operator on the **[`$$ROOT`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#system-variables)** system variable expression:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$sort": {
            "revision": -1
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$name",
            "max_revision": {
                "$max": "$revision"
            },
            "doc": {
                "$first": "$$ROOT"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Output**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "def",
            "max_revision" : 2,
            "doc" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("55aa088a58f2a8f2bd2a3796"),
                "name" : "def",
                "revision" : 2
            }
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "abc",
            "max_revision" : 2,
            "doc" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("55aa088a58f2a8f2bd2a3794"),
                "name" : "abc",
                "revision" : 2
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Learnt many new things such as $$ROOT sys variable.

Comment: Is there a more elegant way to find the document that produced the maximum, without sorting the entire collection? Sorting is very expensive compared to finding a maximum.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [Mongo aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/) to get expected output.

The query will be like following:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $group: {
    _id: "$name",
    "revision": {
        $max: "$revision"
    }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
    "name": "$_id",
    "revision": 1,
    "_id": 0
    }
})
```

**EDIT**

You can use query like following-

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $sort: {
    revision: -1
    }
}, {
    $group: {
    _id: "$name",
    "revision": {
        "$max": "$revision"
    },
    "original": {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
    }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
    "name": "$_id",
    "revision": 1,
    "_id": "$original._id"
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is what exactly I tried before. The issue is that this doesn't give the document id. My requirement is to select those documents with highest revision and do some further operations. Alternatively, if I could get the id of the document, at-least it can be used in 2nd query to get those documents.

Comment: @Sujee You could have avoided this by posting what you have tried in the question. It is recommended to do so. Please read the guidelines/help or do the tour.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. yes. It is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Elyasin Thanks for the note. I'll follow the recommendations.